# How to build MSI for .net core 7 worker service as windows service using Installer (WIX/ Visual Studio Installer Projects)

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer, backgroundworker

How to build MSI for .net core 7 worker service as windows service using Installer (WIX/ Visual Studio Installer Projects)

net core worker service that will be used as a windows service.
Program .cs

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureLogging(options =>
{
    if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
    {
        options.AddFilter<EventLogLoggerProvider>(level => level >= LogLevel.Information);
    }
})
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

    if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
    {
        services.Configure<EventLogSettings>(config =>
        {
            if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
            {
                config.LogName = "Prith Service";
                config.SourceName = "Prith Worker Service";
            }
        });
    }
})
.UseWindowsService()
.Build();
```

I have tried building the Installer using WIX tool  (https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/install_windows_service.html)
I am getting an error on service installation "Service ''(PrithWinService) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privilege to start system service."
The same WIX installer project code works fine for .net framework windows project.

I also looked into using Visual Studio Installer Project, using the Setup Project.
The installation will work but it will not be set up as a service, (we don't want to manually add that as a windows service).
In .net framework windows service, we can add an installer to the service to do that.
In .net core worker service there is no such option, I tried to add the installer manually just to find out .net core doesn't have access to "System.Configuration.Install.Installer"

Any suggestion on how to have the installer project?

Comment: `I am getting an error on service installation` - if you just build your service app and do `sc.exe create PrithService binPath="C:\wherever"` does that work? can you then launch your service?

Comment: Yes, I can Install the service and start the service manually.